# Can't view values of JSON data (alamofire, ios)

Tags: ios

Why can't I view the values in the console? It only lists the structure.  I am using AlamoFire

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `AnyObject` always print like this in console.

**Try this in console**

```
po response as! Dictionay
```

**or**

Use `Print` or `NSLog` to print the value in Console

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the p, print will try to print your values instead your object definition

```
p response
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to "po objectname as! NSObject", if anyone was wondering how I figured it out